# How to place "callbefore" function?

Tags: javascript, callback

How to complete a header function before executing the body function ?

For example, something like in the script

```
var beforeFn = function(callback) {

  setTimeout(function() {

    alert('beforeFn');
    callback();

  }, 1000);
};

var mainFn = function() {
   alert('mainFn');
};
```

and executing it in the way

```
beforeFn(function(){mainFn()})
```

results exactly what I am looking for.

However I am looking to call `mainFn(...)` with `beforeFn()` as a parameter. Probably something like

```
mainFn(beforeFn);
```

How should I get it done ?

[Added]
The `mainFn` waits until the `beforeFn` is fully completed.

[Added]
Added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9owzgasn/

Comment: Where do you want to define the callback for `beforeFn`?

Comment: I don't quite understand how just calling `beforeFn(); mainFn();` in order wouldn't result in the desired output? Also, why do you need the timeout?

Comment: @ekuusela I added timeout just to show the beforeFn could longer time, hence delaying before the mainFn gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var beforeFn = function() {
    alert('beforeFn');
};

var mainFn = function(callback) {
   callback();
   alert('mainFn');
};

mainFn(beforeFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of guessing what you aim at:

```
var mainFn = function( fn_before, fn_cb) {
   alert('mainFn');
   fn_before(fn_cb);
};
```

Call it like:

```
mainFn ( beforeFn, function () { /* whatever */ } );
```